# When $f(x+1)-f(x)=f'(x)$, what are the solutions for $f(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, delay-differential-equations

The question is:

> When $f(x+1)-f(x)=f'(x)$, what are the solutions for $f(x)$?

The most obvious solution is a linear function of the form $f(x)=ax+b$. Is this the only solution?

**Edit**

I should add that $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ to the question.

Comment: We surely know that $f$ is in $C^\infty$. If we would know it is analytic we could use a taylor series to get the unique solution $f(x)=ax+b$. So every other solution must be in $C^\infty$ but can't be analytic.

Comment: Two small observations: (1) If $f$ is a solution, then so is $f'$, $f''$, etc. (2) For any $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, the Mean Value Theorem yields an infinite (strictly increasing) sequence $\{x_0, x_1, \ldots\}$ with $f'(x_0) = f'(x_1) = \cdots$.

Comment: Hasn't this been asked here before?

Comment: $f(x)=c$ is also an obvious solution as each side becomes zero.

Comment: If we take Fourier transform of the both sides, we get $F\cdot e^{iw} - F = F\cdot (iw)$, grouping the fourier image $F$, we get $F=\frac {iw} {e^{iw}-1}$. If we take the inverse fourier of the right hand, we'd get the $f$.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is an example of a [delay differential equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_differential_equation), and it has a very large number of solutions.  I will begin by discussing solutions $f\colon[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$, and then extend to solutions on the real line.

Suppose first that we have defined $f$ on the interval $[0,1]$, say $f(x) = f_0(x)$ for some differentiable function $f_0\colon[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$.  For extending solutions forwards, the best way to write the equation is
$$
f(x+1) \;=\; f(x) + f'(x).
$$
Using this equation, it is not hard to define $f$ on the interval $[1,2]$. Specifically, if $x\in[1,2]$, then
$$
f(x) \;=\; f_0(x-1) + f_0'(x-1).
$$
Note that this function will only be differentiable if $f_0$ was twice differentiable on $[0,1]$.  Moreover, the derivatives at $1$ will only match up if $f_0'(1) = f_0'(0) + f_0''(0)$.  Assuming this is the case, it is easy to extend again to $[2,3]$.  Specifically, if $x\in[2,3]$, then
$$
f(x) \;=\; f(x-1) + f'(x-1) \;=\; f_0(x-2) + 2 f_0'(x-2) + f_0''(x-2).
$$
In general, assuming that:

1. The function $f_0$ is $C^\infty$ on $[0,1]$ and,
2. $f_0^{(k)}(1) = f_0^{(k)}(0) + f_0^{(k+1)}(0)$ for all $k\geq 0$,

we can extend $f$ to all of $[0,\infty)$ by the formula
$$
f(x) \;=\; \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor x\rfloor} \,\binom{\lfloor x\rfloor}{k}f_0^{(k)}(x-\lfloor x\rfloor)
$$

Now let's discuss how to extend backwards.  Assuming we have defined $f$ on $[0,\infty)$, the formula for $f$ on $[-1,0]$ is determined by the initial-value problem
$$
f'(x) + f(x) \;=\; f_0(x+1),\qquad f(0) = f_0(0).
$$
This is a first-order differential equation, so it must have a solution.  Moreover, assuming $f_0$ is $C^\infty$ on $[0,1]$, it follows from the [Picard-Lindelöf Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) that there is a unique $C^\infty$ solution for $f$ on $[-1,0]$.  Note that the derivatives at $0$ will automatically match, since $f_0(1) - f(0) = f_0'(0)$.  Continuing in this fashion, we can extend *any* solution backwards all the way to $-\infty$.

We conclude that *any* function $f_0\colon[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfying the two conditions listed above extends to a solution on the entire real line.

**Edit:** Incidentally, there is a simple integral formula for $f$ on $(-\infty,0]$, which can be used to compute values for $f$ on a computer:
$$
f(x) \;=\; f(0) + e^{-x-1}\int_{x+1}^1 e^{t}\,f(t)\,dt
$$
This can also be used to provide an alternative proof that the function extends backwards, without appealing to existence and uniqueness of ODE's.  I found this formula by solving the initial value problem $f(x) + f'(x) = f(x+1)$ using [integrating factors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor).

Comment: If we normalize $f_0(0)=f_0'(0)=0$, and if we suppose that $0$ is in the support of $f_0$, is there any simple example of $f_0$?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  For example, I would guess that the functions $f_0(x) = ax+b$ are the only _analytic_ possibilities for $f_0$.  For other examples of $f_0$, you need to start with something like a [bump function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function) on $[0,1]$.

Comment: To be more precise, something like $f_0(x) = \mathrm{exp}\left(-x^{-2}(x-1)^{-2}\right)$ would work well.  I've added an explicit formula for the negative part above which should make it possible to define the function $f$ effectively in a computer algebra system.

Comment: Yes, your example definitely works. It was my mistake to say $0$ in the support of $f_0$. Actually I want a litte more: $f_0^{(k)}(0)\ne 0$ for some $k\ge 2$ to exclude bump functions, and now I see achille hui has cleared my doubts. Thank you for your replies.

Comment: Very nice answer!

Answer (score 19):

Let $\lambda = \alpha + \beta i \in \mathbb{C}$ be any root of the equation $\lambda = e^{\lambda} - 1$ subject to $\beta \ge 0$ and $\delta$ any real number, then 
$$f(x) = \Re( e^{\lambda x + i\delta} ) = e^{\alpha x} \cos(\beta x + \delta)\tag{*}$$
will be a $C^{\infty}$ solution for the functional equation $f'(x) = f(x+1) - f(x)$.

For example, $\lambda = e^{\lambda} -1 $ has a root at $\sim 2.088843015613044 + 7.461489285654254 i$.
This gives us following $C^{\infty}$ solution:

$$f(x) \sim e^{ 2.088843015613044\,x}\,\cos(7.461489285654254\,x)$$

[image: Yet another graph for functional equations]

Other solutions can be constructed by forming linear combination of solutions of the form in $(*)$. Please note that $\lambda = e^{\lambda} - 1$ has a double root at $\lambda = 0$,
there are two solutions at $\lambda = 0$ which one can use:

$$ \Re( e^{\lambda x} )\Big|_{\lambda = 0} = 1
\quad\quad\text{ and }\quad\quad
\frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda} \Re( e^{\lambda x} )\Big|_{\lambda = 0} = x
$$

Comment: Very nice!  I would have guessed that there weren't any analytic solutions beyond $f(x) =ax + b$.

Comment: However, your claim that an arbitrary solution can be constructed from these is not obvious to me.  Is there some reason that the solution space is the closure of the span of these solutions?

Comment: @JimBelk Sorry for the confusion. I'm not claiming arbitrary solutions can be constructed from these.

Comment: "Other solutions" simply means there are more solutions that can be constructed, not that every solution can necessarily be constructed in this way.

Comment: @anon, in my previous edit. I'm absent minded and uses the term "general solution". It is no wonder it will confuse others.

Comment: Ah, I see. ${}{}$

Comment: @achillehui Ok, that makes sense.  Although I'm still curious about whether the solutions that you've found might possibly "span" the solution space, in the same way that $\sin(nx)$ and $\cos(nx)$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ span the space of all continuous periodic functions on the interval $[0,2\pi]$.  It seems conceivable that they do, but I don't know enough about delay differential equations to know whether that kind of thing is common.

Comment: @JimBelk, I also suspect the set is complete in certain sense but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Note that $\lambda = e^\lambda - 1 \stackrel{\lambda\neq 1}\Longleftrightarrow -e^{-1} = -(1+\lambda)e^{-(1+\lambda)} \Leftrightarrow \lambda = -(1+W(-e^{-1}))$ where W is the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) (it has multiple branches; the only two real-valued λs solving this are λ=0 and λ=∞, all "sensible" solutions are complex valued) **edit** Why did I even bother calculating this by hand? [alpha can do...](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve[lambda%3De^lambda-1%2Clambda])

Answer (score 14):

Commenting to achille hui's answer, the idea of choosing $\lambda$ comes from the observation that the translation operator $\tau_{h} f (x) = f(x+h)$ corresponds to the exponential of the differential operator

$$\tau_{h}f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(x)}{n!}h^{n} = e^{h d/dx} f(x).$$

on the space of analytic functions. So writing $D = d/dx$, the given equation can be transformed into

$$ e^{D}f(x) - f(x) = Df(x) \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad (e^{D} - 1 - D)f(x) = 0.$$

By making an ansatz that a solution $f(x)$ has the form $f(x) = e^{\lambda x}$, it is easy to see that the equation above is equivalent to $e^{\lambda} - 1 - \lambda = 0$, the very starting point of the achille hui's answer.

Comment: (+1) Yup, this is part of the motivation of my answer. Another one is when one view the functional equation as a problem of finding eigenvectors, the operator involved commute with the translation operator $e^{tD}$, this suggest one to look at common eigenvector for both operators. i.e. ansatz of the form $e^{\lambda x}$.

Comment: Since the $e^{\lambda x}$ form the Eigenbase of $D$, doesn't this somehow indicate that _all_ solutions are obtainable as superpositions of the valid $\lambda$ solutions, similar to Fourier series but summing over the branches of the Lambert W function (see [my other comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389847/when-fx1-fx-fx-what-are-the-solutions-for-fx#comment837092_389912)) instead of integers? (also @achillehui)

Answer (score 2):

**Partial answer.** If $f(x)$ is the a polinomial function say $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^na_kx^k$ then
$$
\sum_{k=0}^na_k(x+1)^k-\sum_{k=0}^na_kx^k=\sum_{k=0}^nka_kx^{k-1}
$$ 
 For $x=1$ we have
$$
\sum_{k=0}^na_k2^k-\sum_{k=0}^na_k=\sum_{k=0}^nka_k
$$
If $n=2$  then
$
a_0+2a_1+4a_2-a_0-a_1+a_2=a_1+2a_2\implies a_2=0.
$
In general case for all $n>1$ we have for any no root $x_0$ of $f(x)$ or $p(x)= (x+1)^n-x^n$ that 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^na_k(x_0+1)^k-\sum_{k=0}^na_kx_0^k-\sum_{k=0}^nka_kx^{k-1}=0 \implies [(x_0+1)^n-x_0^n]a_n=0\implies a_n=0
$$

Soon the solution can not be a polynomial of degree greater than 1.

Answer (score 0):

An exponential function $a^x$ with base $a$ satisfying the equation

$$a^a-ea=0$$

is the solution.

The equation has two roots:

$${\large a}_1=0.2592463566483049762658328267922644867392517823397669639360784269929\ldots$$

$${\large a}_2=2.2399778876565500700638977660928972654111884831688969821454636850130\ldots$$

See this question for more details:

[Closed form solution to $\frac{1}{a-1}= \log a$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1169221/closed-form-solution-to-frac1a-1-log-a)