# Differential equation $f'(x)=\alpha\cdot f(x-1)^\beta$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, delay-differential-equations

Is there a way to solve $$f'(x)=\alpha\cdot f(x-1)^\beta,$$ where $\alpha>0,\beta\neq0.$

I know that if the arguments matched, I could use separation of variables to get $\frac{1}{1-\beta}f(x)^{1-\beta}=ax+C$, unless $\beta=1$, in which case I get a log. Here though, I don't even know how to start because the derivative is in terms of $x$ while the function itself is in terms of $x-1$.

Comment: This is an example of a [delay differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_differential_equation) because the derivative of $f$ is related to values of the function at previous times (just one previous point in time in this case).

Comment: At las many solutions exist on left-bounded intervals. For example, define $f$ arbitryrily (continuous of course) on $[0,1]$ with the sole restriction that $f'(1)$ exists and is $=\alpha f(0)^\beta$. Then you can extend to $[0,\infty)$ successively by integrating

Comment: You can see this techniques of continuation [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1365327/what-function-satisfies-fx-f2x)