# Every continuous and bounded $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = \int_x^{x+1} f(y) dy$ for every $x$, is constant

Tags: integration, continuity

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous and bounded function such that for all $x$:
>   $$f(x) = \int_x^{x+1} f(y) dy.$$
>   Prove that $f$ is constant.

I could have progressed if it was given that $f$ is differentiable, but with such less info I am finding it tough.

Comment: Maybe you can conclude from the identity that $f$ indeed is differentiable?

Comment: Is it because RHS is differentiable?

Comment: @AyanBiswas yes, use the FTC to show the RHS is differentiable. Then since RHS = LHS you see LHS is as well (because they are the same thing)

Comment: Yes, that is the argument.

Comment: I think the solution is that $f$ is analytic @Winther and integrating over the unit circle $\int_0^{2 \pi} f'(e^{it}) e^{-i n x} dt$  shows that $f(x) = ax+b$

Comment: @user1952009 What is $n$?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff : the $n$th coef in the Taylor series. extracting $c_n z^n$ from $\sum_k c_k z^k$, and using that $c_n z^n$ is solution only if $n = 1$

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389847/when-fx1-fx-fx-what-are-the-solutions-for-fx) is related to this problem.

Comment: @user1952009 I don't think that is enough based on the example function in an answer in the question linked to above (an analytical function not equal to $a+bz$ which satisfy $f'(z) = f(z+1) - f(z)$).

Comment: @Winther : I did not get where there is a counter-example in your link.

Answer (score 4):

Since $f$ is a bounded function it is a tempered distribution. Then the Fourier transformation of
$f'(x) = f(x+1)-f(x)$ gives us
\begin{equation*}
i\xi F(\xi) = e^{i\xi}F(\xi)-F(\xi) \Leftrightarrow F(\xi)\cdot(i\xi -e^{i\xi}+1) = 0
\end{equation*}
where $F$ is the Fourier transform of $f$. But
\begin{equation*}
i\xi -e^{i\xi}+1 = 0 \Leftrightarrow \left\{\begin{array}{l}
\cos \xi = 1\\
\xi -\sin \xi = 0
\end{array}
 \right. \Leftrightarrow \xi = 0 \text{ (double)}.
\end{equation*}
Consequently
\begin{equation*}
\xi^{2}F(\xi) = 0 \Leftrightarrow F(\xi) = A\delta(\xi) + B\delta'(\xi)
\end{equation*}
where $A$ and $B$ are constants. After inverse Fourier transformation we have
\begin{equation*}
f(x) = \dfrac{A}{2\pi} + \dfrac{Bx}{i2\pi}.
\end{equation*}
But $f$ is bounded. Thus $B = 0$ and $f$ is constant.