# Is there any intuition why this relation holds?

Tags: functions, derivatives

If

$$D=\frac{d}{dx}$$ then we have

$$\exp(D)f(x)=f(x+1)$$

What does it mean? Is there any intuition behind it?

Comment: See [this](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/61252/why-do-bernoulli-numbers-arise-everywhere/61256#61256).

Comment: Ah! Of course! It is just expanding $f(x+1)$ as a power series centered at $f(x)$. Nice

Comment: See my [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185354/exponential-of-the-differential-operator).