# Continuation of a system of recursive finite differences

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, finite-differences

Suppose I have a system of recursive functions of discrete time

$$\mathbf{x}(t+1) = \mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}(t)$$

where $\mathbf{A}$ is a square matrix.
How can I find a system of first order ordinary differential equations

$$\mathbf{\dot{x}}(t) = \mathbf{B}\mathbf{x}(t)$$

so that, sharing the initial state $\mathbf{x}(0)$,
every solution $(t, \textbf{x})$ to the former
is also a solution to the latter?

Letting $\mathbf{B} = \mathbf{A}$ doesn’t work.

Comment: The existing answers are technically correct; you do in fact want to find a square matrix $\mathbf{B}$ where $e^\mathbf{B} = \mathbf{A}$. However, this is not necessarily trivial. Sometimes there will be no solution; other times there will be infinitely many. Did you have any particular $\mathbf{A}$ in mind?

Comment: @ChadGroft I supposed finding the matrix logarithm of $\mathbf{A}$ would find me $\mathbf{B}$. The system that inspired the question was $\mathbf{y}(t + 1) = \begin{bmatrix} -0.7 & 0.05 \\ 0.7 & -0.05 \end{bmatrix} \mathbf{y}(t)$.

Comment: Yeah, that matrix is singular, so it can't possibly have a logarithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $D$ is differential operator, then

$$
D{\bf x}(t)= \dot{\bf x}(t) \tag{1}
$$

[Moreover](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185354/exponential-of-the-differential-operator),

$$
e^D {\bf x}(t) = {\bf x}(t + 1) \tag{2}
$$

In you case the operator $D$ is just a matrix ${\bf B}$, so that

$$
e^{\bf B} = {\bf A}
$$